# How do you properly access the global context in Node.js? Building a jQuery Plugin with Node.js

Tags: jquery, node.js

I am trying to build a simple jQuery plugin with node.js.  I need to be able to access the global context, which in the browser is the window object, but haven't figured out how yet.

Here's the setup:

#### 1. `/spec/spec_runner.js`

```
//fake browser window
var jsdom       = require('jsdom').jsdom,
    sys         = require('sys'),
    window      = jsdom().createWindow(),
    coffee      = require('coffee-script'),
    jasmine     = require('jasmine-node'),
    underscore  = require('underscore'),
    exec        = require('child_process').exec;
global.jQuery   = require("jquery");
global.$        = global.jQuery;
global._        = underscore;
global.window   = window;

var plugin = require("../lib/my-plugin.js");
global.Model = plugin.Model;
```

#### 2. `/lib/my-plugin.js`

```
var Model = function() {
  console.log(window.document);
}

Model.prototype.doSomething = function() {
  console.log(window.document);
}
```

Problem is, that `window` attribute is not correct.  I can get it to work if I do this:

```
Model.prototype.doSomething = function() {
  console.log(global.window.document);
}
```

...but that's a problem for when I'm running this in the browser.

How do I get it so I can write the plugin and test it using node.js, but it has no (or at least a standardized) reference to `global` or `exports`?

Comment: Looking at http://blog.nodejitsu.com/jsdom-jquery-in-5-lines-on-nodejs I see that you need to use `jsdom.jQueryify(window, '/path/to/jquery.js', function (window, jquery) {` would that help? Scope that article and see where it doesn't match up with what you're doing ... I've not done jsdom and jQuery on the node proper, so I'm not entirely sure just yet...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's working fine for me in this simplified test case:

**scope_test.js**

```
var jsdom = require('jsdom').jsdom;
var window = jsdom().createWindow();
global.window = window;

var test = require('./plugin_test.js')
global.Model = new test.Model();
Model.doSomething();
```

**plugin_test.js**

```
exports.Model = Model;

function Model() {
  console.log(window.document);
}

Model.prototype.doSomething = function() {
  console.log(window.document);
}
```

Result:

```
$ node scope_test.js 
{ _childNodes: 
   [ { _attributes: [Object],
       _ownerDocument: [Circular],
       _childNodes: [Object],
       style: [Object],
       _childrenList: [Object],
       _childNodesList: [Object],
       _nodeName: 'html',
       _tagName: 'html',
       _created: true,

....


{ _childNodes: 
   [ { _attributes: [Object],
       _ownerDocument: [Circular],
       _childNodes: [Object],
       style: [Object],
       _childrenList: [Object],
       _childNodesList: [Object],
       _nodeName: 'html',
       _tagName: 'html',
       _created: true,
```